# how to solve: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

After running flutter I am getting this error, I've already switched to master channel and downgraded flutter and also switched to stable channel and downgraded. I've also deleted pubspec.lock then ran pub get and still getting this error.

This is the whole error message:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
../../../sdks/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/states_rebuilder-1.3.2/lib/src/bloc_provider.dart:22:17: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../sdks/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
        context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget;
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/enel/sdks/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/enel/sdks/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Go to `pubspec.yaml` file, and try doing `Packages get | Pub get`, and then build the project again.

or else try this:

```
flutter clean and flutter pub get
```

in the terminal, and the issue solved!

Hope this resolves!

Comment: I've done it and I still get the same error